# Mockito upgrade 3.10 to 3.11 causes crash

Tags: android, mockito

I just upgraded Mockito from 3.10.0 to 3.11.0 in our Android project, and now, running instrumentation tests crashes with the exception below. Any suggestion?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy10.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:250)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:83)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1954)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1865)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.FragmentTestRunner.createNavController(FragmentTestRunner.kt:127)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.FragmentTestRunner.access$createNavController(FragmentTestRunner.kt:44)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.FragmentTestRunner$runTest$1.invokeSuspend(FragmentTestRunner.kt:58)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.FragmentTestRunner$runTest$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.FragmentTestRunner$runTest$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:332)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source:1)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:82)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source:1)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.FragmentTestRunner.runTest(FragmentTestRunner.kt:55)
    at com.oslonokkel.ui.fragments.FeedbackFragmentTest.allFieldsEmpty(FeedbackFragmentTest.kt:41)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
    at com.oslonokkel.utils.RetryTestRule$statement$1.evaluate(RetryTestRule.kt:27)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:395)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@f4afab0
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:65)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:50)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:20)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getMockMaker(Plugins.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:28)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:52)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to resolve the class file version of the current VM: This JVM's version string does not seem to be valid: 0
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion$VersionLocator$Unresolved.resolve(ClassFileVersion.java:558)
    at net.bytebuddy.ClassFileVersion.ofThisVm(ClassFileVersion.java:276)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.ParameterList$ForLoadedExecutable.of(ParameterList.java:205)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$ForLoadedMethod.getParameters(MethodDescription.java:1179)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder.compile(TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder.java:82)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$ImplementationDelegate$ForStaticMethod.of(MethodDelegation.java:948)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$WithCustomProperties.to(MethodDelegation.java:1512)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation$WithCustomProperties.to(MethodDelegation.java:1493)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation.to(MethodDelegation.java:271)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.<init>(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.<init>(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:37)
    at org.mockito.android.internal.creation.AndroidByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(AndroidByteBuddyMockMaker.java:22)
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is known to the mockito project and reported there: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2316